# Where is the Spring jar file located?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jar, classpath

I'm trying to install Spring Boot using Maven. I use IntelliJ Community Edition (that doesn't have a built-in support for Spring). Therefore, I entered here: http://start.spring.io/, and downloaded an initial Spring Boot project for Maven. The first thing I did is running "install" in order to install the dependencies.

When the installation completed, I looked at the Java file inside `src/main/java` folder:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I get errors: "`Can't resolve symbol springframework/SpringApplication`". I understand that these errors show, as my Spring jar file is not included in the classpath.

My question is where is this file located, so I can add it to the classpath?

My `pom.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have only one jar file in the target directory:

```
$ ls target/*.jar
target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Do you have maven installed? Is your pom properly setup? Spring should be available in maven central, so building (and running) with maven should not be a problem.

Comment: show your pom file

Comment: Take a glance at the official documentation. -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html. By default, the jar is in the /target folder.

Comment: @viruskimera, I added the pom.xml file to the original post.

Comment: @Dani, I have only one jar file in /target folder which is not the spring's one.

Comment: Why do you *expect* to have the Spring jar there?

Comment: @DaveNewton, this is what Dani's link says.

Comment: No, *your* jar ends up in the target.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found it under: 
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/